# How to I detect model changes at a component level?

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to be able to detect model changes (not only input from the frontend but backend/application changes) at a component level.

I would like to set the focus of a component element when model properties meet certain criteria.

I'm using Angular 7.

I have the following model:

```
export class Hello  {
  enabled: boolean;
  name: string;
  focus: boolean;
  selected: boolean;
  text: string;
}
```

And the following component references the model:

```
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() model: Hello;
}
```

Say now I have a process that updates the model on the backend, for example, the "focus" boolean changes often, I want to be able to detect that change in the component and focus on an element.

Comment: The question isn't clear at the moment. Could you please post your code and state what exactly are you trying to achieve with respect to your code?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use RxJS to that. Just use `subscription` in component on events from your application service with criteria subject.

Answer (score 0):

if I get you right

> detect model changes (not only input from the frontend but backend/application changes)

you want to be informed in your component, when your model changes.

I would suggest using [Observables](https://angular.io/guide/observables). You can subscribe to the Observable (e.g. login state).
You do not have to look for changes, but would be informed about changes. In connection with your UI, the changes can be bound, that the UI updates automatically.

Could be sth. like:

```
loggedIn$: Observable<Boolean>;

public ngOnInit() {
    this.loggedIn$ = this.loginService.getLoginState()
}
```

When it comes to Observables "State Management" is really interesting - e.g. [RXJS](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/) or [NGXS](https://www.ngxs.io/) when it comes to Angular.
Have a look, at [some articles](https://medium.jonasbandi.net/the-most-simple-state-management-solution-for-angular-1d32706e6f1c).

Comment: even NGRX is there https://ngrx.io/docs but looks like more complex than NGXS

Comment: I prefer NGXS because it is easier